# find standard deviation in a stack for special rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a stack as following, I have to find the month when A has lowest standard deviation for AAPL

```
                    A   
Date                        
2000-07-03  AAPL    3.290673    
            ADBE    31.756767       
            ADI     54.067356
2000-07-04  AAPL    6.660673    
            ADBE    71.956767       
            ADI     44.767356   
2020-08-07  AAPL    210.399994  
            ADBE    24.88
            ADI     55.09
2020-08-17  AAPL    329.399994  
            ADBE    64.88
            ADI     99.09
2020-09-10  AAPL    70.39
            ADBE    14.81
            ADI     65.69
2020-09-20  AAPL    140.39
            ADBE    83.51
            ADI     57.69
```

Comment: `df[df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'AAPL'].min()`?

Comment: How do you define standard deviation on one single number?

Comment: @MohammadJafarMashhadi The standard deviation has to be calculated across the dates for APPL

Comment: @Khaned are you sure you have a multiindex?

Comment: @Khaned please provide your expected output

Comment: @It_is_Chris sorry i made a mistake earlier. I get all the rows with df[df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'AAPL'] but how do I calculate which month has the lowest SD?

Comment: @Khaned what do you mean by "lowest standard deviation"

Comment: @It_is_Chris yes

Comment: @Khaned your example only has one value for A for each month. You cannot calculate the standard deviation with a single value. Is there more data that is missing from your example? If so, please create a sample dataframe to that accurately represents your actual dataframe.

Comment: @It_is_Chris Each month has multiple dates with data, I wanted to avoid confusion for people

Comment: @It_is_Chris I have updated the dataframe in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# sample data
s = """Date,Stock,A
7/3/2000,AAPL,3.290673
7/3/2000,ADBE,31.756767
7/3/2000,ADI,54.067356
7/4/2000,AAPL,6.660673
7/4/2000,ADBE,71.956767
7/4/2000,ADI,44.767356
8/7/2020,AAPL,210.399994
8/7/2020,ADBE,24.88
8/7/2020,ADI,55.09
8/17/2020,AAPL,329.399994
8/17/2020,ADBE,64.88
8/17/2020,ADI,99.09
9/10/2020,AAPL,70.39
9/10/2020,ADBE,14.81
9/10/2020,ADI,65.69
9/20/2020,AAPL,140.39
9/20/2020,ADBE,83.51
9/20/2020,ADI,57.69
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))

# convert to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index(['Date', 'Stock'])

# filter frame and reset the index
f = df[df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'AAPL'].reset_index()
# groupby month and year and calc the std of each group
std = f.groupby([f['Date'].dt.month, f['Date'].dt.year])['A'].std()
# return the index of the min std
std.idxmin()

# output is below, which is the month and the year of the lowest std
# (7, 2000)
```

Or if you want to rerun the series change `std.idxmin()` to `std[std == std.min()]`